# How to integrate Joystick support or Xbox 360 support into SDL

Tags: c++, controller, sdl

I'm trying to find examples or tutorials for coding the Xbox 360 into my project. So far I've been only using SDL_keysym for the movement of my sprites using the arrow keys and WASD keys. Wondering how I integrate Xbox 360(preferably) or Joystick support in.

Below are the codes I have currently for the movement of my sprite Spaceship1 using arrows and WASD keys. Forgive me as the codes are disorganized.

```
struct oSprite 
{
int m_nTotalFrames;
int m_nCurrentFrame;
int m_nFrameWidth;
int m_nFrameHeight;

fVector2 m_vPosition;

SDL_Surface* m_pImage;

bool        m_bIsHuman;
oControls   m_oControls;
oControls   m_oAltControls;
};

bool Update()
{
fVector2 vKeyPresses;

Uint8* paunKeyStates = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
float fMoveSpeed = 0.5f;

if(paunKeyStates[g_Spaceship1.m_oControls.m_nUpButton] || paunKeyStates[g_Spaceship1.m_oAltControls.m_nUpButton])
{
    vKeyPresses.y -= fMoveSpeed;
}

if(paunKeyStates[g_Spaceship1.m_oControls.m_nDownButton] || paunKeyStates[g_Spaceship1.m_oAltControls.m_nDownButton])
{
    vKeyPresses.y += fMoveSpeed;
}

if(paunKeyStates[g_Spaceship1.m_oControls.m_nLeftButton] || paunKeyStates[g_Spaceship1.m_oAltControls.m_nLeftButton])
{
    vKeyPresses.x -= fMoveSpeed;
}

if(paunKeyStates[g_Spaceship1.m_oControls.m_nRightButton] || paunKeyStates[g_Spaceship1.m_oAltControls.m_nRightButton])
{
    vKeyPresses.x += fMoveSpeed;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the init of th SDL try this

```
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK)
```